# unpacking pythons struct.pack in another language

Tags: python, byte, struct.pack

I want to "unpack" OR de-serialize the formatted data that is outputed from python's struct.pack() function. The data is sent over the network to another platform that uses Java only.

**The Python function that sends data over the network, uses this formater:**

```
def formatOutputMsg_Array(self, mac, arr):
        mac_bin = mac.encode("ascii");
        mac_len = len(mac_bin);

        arr_bin = array.array('d', arr).tobytes();
        arr_len = len(arr_bin);

        m = struct.pack('qqd%ss%ss' % (mac_len, arr_len), mac_len, arr_len, time.time(), mac_bin, arr_bin);

        return m
```

Here are the docs for python's struct (refer to section 7.3.2.2. Format Characters):
https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html

**1) The issue is what does 'qqd%ss%ss' mean ???**

**Does it mean ->** long,long,double,char,char,[],char[],char,char[],char[]

2) **why is modulo "%"** used  here with a tuple 'qqd%ss%ss' **%** **(mac_len, arr_len)** ?

Comment: You posted a link to a table that says `q` means `long long`, so why do you think it would mean `long` instead of `long long`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument to `pack` is the *result* of the expression `'qqd%ss%ss' % (mac_len, arr_len)`, where the two `%s` are replaced by the values of the given variables. Assuming `mac_len == 8` and `arr_len == 4`, for example, the result is `qqd8s4s`. `s` preceded by a number simply means to copy the given bytes for that format into the result.

Comment: Therefore giving your example does this mean long,long,double,8,char[8],4,char[4] , therefore in order to de-serialize I will read 4 bytes as a long, 4 bytes as a long, 8 bytes as a double, 8 characters , 4 characters?

Comment: Right. The `%` is just used to create the correct packing format, since there is no way to pack "whatever is in the corresponding variable". It would be nice if you could give a format string like `qqd*s*s`, but alas. Note that the first two longs would appear to be the lengths of the two strings that follow the double.